# OnCollisionEnter not triggering audio clip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make it so that when the 'Player' collides with the ball, an audio sample triggers. I cant see why the trigger would not go off looking at my code and inspector.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerSFX : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip kicked;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.clip = kicked;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Inspector view of ball]

Colliding the ball and the player in the scene should trigger the audio clip but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `audioSource.PlayOneShot(kicked);` instead of `audioSource.clip = kicked; audioSource.Play();`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and inspector. Those work fine. Make sure `Collider` and `Rigidbody` components have been added to the target game object (the game object with the `Player` tag) and `is trigger` is not checked at the `Collider` component. also check the tag of the target game object.